# How can I use customer error messages on form fields generated by Ruby on Rails when using the jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin with customer error messages in a form on my site. The way to specify customer messages is as follows:

```
$('#user_new').validate({
    messages: {
        user_email: {
        required: "dd ",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address, example: you@yourdomain.com"
    }
    }
});
```

This will apply the custom error messages to the input with the name of `user_email`. This code works okay. The problem is that the fields have names such as `user[email]` because they are generated by Rails using `form_for`. But this won't work:

```
$('#user_new').validate({
    messages: {
        user[email]: {
        required: "dd ",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address, example: you@yourdomain.com"
    }
    }
});
```

The `user[email]` part causes a javascript error. Has anyone got custom messages working on Rails generated input fields with this plugin? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just quoting the javascript array keys?

```
messages: {
    "user[email]": {
    required: "dd ",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address, example: you@yourdomain.com"
}
```